# Is there a way to mark all items as read in fastladder?

Tags: rss, rss-reader

Greetings fellow web citizens,

I just migrated from the soon to be defunct bloglines to [fastladder.com](http://fastladder.com/) following an answer to a question here at webapps.

I'm very impressed with how well my fairly large opml file exported from bloglines imported onto fastladder.com and on top of all it supports openID which is a feature I appreciate very much.

I however have a smallish issue all my feeds are marked as unread and most of them has 200 entries, I can't find a "mark all as read button" anywhere in the UI.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Edit button (next to Reload) at the top of the sidebar. Then click "Select All" and finally "Mark as read".